# C#でWEB上の画像をダウンロードし20kbまで圧縮させたいです。

Tags: c#

簡単な計算ができません。
画像が複数枚あります。それぞれ1MBを超えるランダムのサイズです。
それを全てダウンロードまではできたんですが、指定したファイルサイズに圧縮できません。よろしく居お願いします。
計算部分はこれです。fi.Lengthは元のファイルサイズです。

```
long imgsize = (20L/fi.Length);
```

また、できればへんてこなソースコードを改良していただきたいです。

```
ImageCodecInfo jgpEncoder = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg);
System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder myEncoder = System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality;
EncoderParameters myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);


WebClient wc = new WebClient();
try
{
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
    {
        wc.DownloadFile(lines[i], dirName + "\\" + (i + 1) + ".jpg");

        Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(@"C:\download\"+now+"\\"+(i+1)+".jpg");
        System.IO.FileInfo fi=new System.IO.FileInfo(@"C:\download\" + now + "\\" + (i + 1) + ".jpg");
        long imgsize = (20L/fi.Length);
        EncoderParameter myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, imgsize);
        myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;
        bmp1.Save(@"C:\download\"+now+"\\resized\\"+(i+1)+"s.jpg", jgpEncoder, myEncoderParameters);

    }
    balloon = lines.Length + "枚の画像を保存しました";
}
catch (WebException exc)
{
    Console.WriteLine(exc.Message + "\r\n");
    balloon = "エラーが発生しました";
}
```

Comment: さらにできれば、
画像の大きさを横２５０ｐｘにしたいです！

Comment: そもそも圧縮が困難なファイルという可能性は？

Comment: 全てJPEG画像です！全てJPEG拡張子です

Comment: JPEG画像であれば、既にJPEGの時点で圧縮済みなので、それ以上圧縮は困難だと思います。

Comment: JPG画像をJPG画像に圧縮するのが趣旨です！一応上記ソースで圧縮はできてます。ただ処理する全ての画像サイズを20kb以下まで圧縮させたいだけです

Comment: 参考にしたMDSNサイトです
[リンク](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/bb882583%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: 250pxに縮小しつつ、20kbに圧縮したいです。

Comment: 解像度を落とすしかない。世界の天才達が頑張って頑張った結果があのサイズですよｗ

Comment: FYI: JPEG→JPEG再圧縮の場合、エンコーダによる微妙な性能差と微調整の余地はあるものの、基本的に(1)画品質を犠牲にする、(2)解像度を小さくするしか、ファイルサイズを劇的に落とす(1M→20k)ことはできません。なお、JPEG自体は非常に古いコーデックで性能もそこそこなので、JPEG2000やJPEG-HDRといった新しいコーデックで再圧縮すると、画質や解像度を犠牲にせずにファイルサイズを小さくすることも出来ます。ただし、普及しているとは言い難いため、表示アプリは限定されてしまいますね。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 指定したファイルサイズに圧縮できません。

まず一般論として、JPEGによる静止画像圧縮では、目標出力サイズを指定して圧縮するのは困難です。

JPEG圧縮の原理的には、映像品質を決める一つの値(Q値)しか制御するパラメータが存在しません。このパラメータを用いて、サイズが小さいが映像が汚い／サイズが大きいが映像は綺麗のトレードオフから選択します。

`EncoderParameter`に指定する[`Encoder.Quality`フィールド](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.drawing.imaging.encoder.quality.aspx)では、「出力品質」を値0～100で指定できるだけで、それ以上の細かい制御はできません。

一つの解法として、出力ファイルサイズが目標サイズを下回るまで、`Encoder.Quality`フィールドの値を下げながら（画質を下げながら）何度もエンコードしてみるという手はあります。

---

`Encoder.Quality`フィールドの説明は上記のとおりですから、質問にある実装コードは論理的に誤っています。`20L/fi.Length`で算出される値に妥当性がありません。

```
System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder myEncoder = System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality;
long imgsize = (20L/fi.Length);
EncoderParameter myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, imgsize);
```

**追記**
`Quality`の指定は値0-100ですが、これは百分率(%)のような直観的なパラメータではありません。残念ながら、指定値を半分にしたからサイズが半分になり品質が半分になる、というものではありません。

`Quality`値と出力サイズの関係は、下記サイトの情報が参考になるかと思います。ただし、対象とする画像の種類で結構かわりますから、あくまで目安としてみて下さい。
http://www.ipentec.com/document/document.aspx?page=csharp-save-image-to-jpeg

Comment: そうなのですか。ではフリーソフト縮小専用を使って圧縮していこうと思います。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました。yohjpさんの言うとおり、ループにしなければできませんでした。
無理やりループで完成しました。

```
long ex = 80L;
EncoderParameter myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, ex);
myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;
bmpSrcHalf.Save(@"C:\OKADA\download\" + now + "\\resized\\" + (i + 1) + "ss.jpg", jgpEncoder, myEncoderParameters);

System.IO.FileInfo fic = new System.IO.FileInfo(@"C:\OKADA\download\" + now + "\\resized\\" + (i + 1) + "ss.jpg");

while (fic.Length > 160000)
{
    myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, (ex=ex-3));
    myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;
    bmpSrcHalf.Save(@"C:\OKADA\download\" + now + "\\resized\\" + (i + 1) + "ss.jpg", jgpEncoder, myEncoderParameters);
    fic = new System.IO.FileInfo(@"C:\OKADA\download\" + now + "\\resized\\" + (i + 1) + "ss.jpg");
}
```

Comment: yohjpさんも書かれていますが、ファイルサイズは品質パラメータに比例しません。偶然それらしいサイズになることはあっても、あまり意味のある指定ではないということはご承知おきください。（参考：品質とファイルサイズの比較  http://hp.vector.co.jp/authors/VA032610/JPEGFormat/ratio.htm）

Comment: Quarity は画質エンコーダなのでサイズと比例しません。指定のサイズになる様に何度もパラメータを変更しながら実行しないとQuarityをいくらにするかは分からないという意味です。発色数によってファイルサイズは変わってしまいます。ちなみにファイルサイズを小さくしたいという要件であればCompressionを使う方が良いと思います。

Comment: @mattn [`Encoder.Compression`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.drawing.imaging.encoder.compression%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)は用途が違う気がしますし、JPEGでは使えないかと。

Comment: @unarist その様ですね。Qualityしかサイズを抑える方法が無いようです。 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882583.aspx